# FB_Graph: An error occurred. Please try again later

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, facebook-graph-api, fb-graph

I am using fb_graph for my rails app.
I just followed nov/fb_graph app.
It was working fine till last week, i was able yo login and could get user information.
But suddenly i am getting error. 
I didnt change anything in my app.
my app_id, screat_id everything is correct.

Even i am getting error when i close that facebook error window like

Graph::Auth::VerificationFailed
Facebook cookie not found

Could any one got through this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this just because of URL mistake

whatever website url is specified should be correct.

i mentioned website url as http://localhost:3000/ and domain as localhost

but in my browser i was running http://0.0.0.0:3000/ that was the actual problem so i ran server as localhost:3000 now its working fine. Because we mentioned site url as localhost fb will redirect to same, if we r running 0.0.0.0:3000 it will rise error that Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.

thank you